# JavaScript / Lit-element safe way to parse HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xss, lit-element

I am getting some html from my server that I want to put into my page. However I want it to be sanitized (just in case).

However I am not quite sure how to do this.

So far I've tried:

```
<div .innerHTML="${body}"></div>
```

Since that should parse it as HTML but I am not 100% sure that this is the best way.

I have also looked at online sanitizers but haven't been able to find any that match my project (`Lit-element` web component).

Is there a better way to parse HTML and if so how?

Comment: "Best" and "better" are very opinion-based ways of describing what you want. Without knowing what criteria makes up "better" and "best", I would say this question is primarily opinion-based...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Take a look at the DOMParser interface API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

```
document.getElementById('my-target').append(new DOMParser().parseFromString(data, 'text/html').body.children);
```

Comment: Answers which provide an explanation of posted code are upvoted more often and downvoted less often that those which do not.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear whether you want to render the html as html or as text.

I seem to remember that [lit-html](/questions/tagged/lit-html) does some things behind the scenes to produce secure templates but surprisingly I cannot find official content to back up that statement. [Others have asked about this before](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html/issues/759).

In that [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html/issues/759) we can see that Mike Samuel mentions that what you're doing is **not** secure.
*You can trust Mike Samuel: he's worked in the security field at Google and I had the privilege to listen to [one of his talks on the topic two years ago](https://confpad.io/2018-10-06-nordicjs-2018/21-achieving-secure-software-through-redesign).*

[image]

Here's a quick example:

```html
<p .innerHTML=${'<button onclick="alert(42)">click</button>'}></p>
```

This renders a button which produces an alert when you click on it. In this example the JavaScript code is harmless but it's not hard to imagine something way more dangerous.

However this simply renders the code as string. The content is somehow escaped and therefore totally harmless.

```html
<p>${'<button onclick="alert(42)">click</button>'}></p>
```

In fact similar to React's [dangerouslySetInnerHTML attribute](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) you need to "opt out" from secure templating via `lit-html` [unsafeHTML directive](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#unsafehtml):

> Renders the argument as HTML, rather than text.
>
> Note, this is unsafe to use with any user-provided input that hasn't been
> sanitized or escaped, as it may lead to cross-site-scripting vulnerabilities.

```html
<p>${unsafeHTML('<button onclick="alert(42)">click</button>')}></p>
```

---

About `DOMParser#parseFromString`

In this [introductory article](https://web.dev/trusted-types/) about [trusted-types](/questions/tagged/trusted-types) we can see that this method is a known XSS sink.

Sure it won't execute `<script>` blocks but it won't sanitise the string for you. You are still at risk of XSS here:

```html
<p .innerHTML="${(new DOMParser()).parseFromString('<button onclick="alert(42)">click</button>','text/html').body.innerHTML}"></p>
```